# reduce HDFS directory replication factor (setrep)

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've a case where I have a table (internal, partitioned) in Hive in which I use to load data from file.

I reduced the replication factor of that particular directory via setrep as 2. After this when I'm trying to load the data, nothing gets loaded. The MR job executes successfully but nothing gets in the table.

No changes in INSERT command or table structure even. I can't get a hold on what's going on.

As a quick workaround I tried reverting back the replication factor (only of that directory) to its original value i.e., 3 but no effect.

HDP: 2.1
Hive: 0.14

Any explanations to this & a workaround as well would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the data and the insert query. Maybe you are simply inserting an empty file?

Comment: The insert query is like this:
Insert into schemaB.tableNameB PARTITION(colPartition) Select colPartition, colA, colB, colC from schemaA.tableNameA;

The schemaA.tableNameA is a staging table where I insert the original file first & then insert it into final table.

The data is also present; a 300 GB file. The column structure is also exact. I was doing this activity already; the only variable changed is the replication factor I set as explained in the query above.